# Why do future_statements in Python need to be placed before everything?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pep8, pep

[PEP 236](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0236/) states clearly that all `future_statements` must appear near the top of a module, with only comments, docstrings and the like allowed before them.

I understand that this isn't debatable as a programming practice - it's the rules and they're clear. However, I can't google myself an answer as to *why* it was decided to be an error rather than just a violation of recommended practices when you fail to place your `future_statement` at the very top (aka, a warning).

Is it because this way, modules that import their own versions of names that the `future_statement` will import, will be able to override them, thus ensuring they'll work correctly? Is it to maintain some sort of strong code clarity so that proper coding practices aren't broken because of potential disasters if a `__future__` import is accidentally ignored? The PEP isn't enlightening on this and I can't get any leads to finding out why.

Comment: *A future statement is a directive to the compiler that a particular module should be compiled using syntax or semantics that will be available in a specified future release of Python.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`__future__` statements potentially even have effects on parsing (example: `unicode_literals`, `print_function`), as they may modify (or rather switch to a different version of) the grammar. They thus must be known as early as possible. They also certainly have effects on code generation (`division`).

There are are thus good design reasons to force those statements to be at the start of the parsing and the compilation, in addition to the clarity concerns.

Other imported modules do not have any effect on what is going on in *your* module with respect to `__future__`. Which is a good thing, because otherwise other modules could break your module by importing `print_function` from `__future__`.

Comment: So it's because `__future__` imports are special and they're capable of influencing the parser, hence if they were allowed to be placed anywhere, like other `import`s, the parser would become too complicated or in our current state, would fail, correct?

Comment: Exactly. Also, how would the effect of ``from __future__ import print_function`` be scoped if it was placed inside a function? Would it only affect that function? Or would the parser have to switch back to the non-``print_function`` grammar when the function is completely parsed? These are questions whose answers introduce horrible complexity and readability issues.

Comment: This seems to answer my question adequately, I'll just wait for a bit to accept it just to provide the opportunity for others to add their answers if anyone is around. If nothing better appears, which I doubt anything can answer better than this, I'll accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

At a guess, it's to avoid the following kind of situation:

```
print "yo"
from __future__ import print_function
```

Is the print statement a syntax error or not? It depends if the future import applies to the whole file or just from that point on. Better to make it unequivocally an error not to be the import at the top.

Comment: But that can happen with any `import` and it may be intentional. A warning is definitely warranted, but an error feels like there's something much more dangerous that's possible.